# beginning of the proof of fundamental solution of Poisson's equation - Evan's PDE

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

in Evan's PDE book (see pic below)

[image]

$D^2f$ being the hessian matrix and $\Delta f = Trace(D^2f)$

I can't see why the highlighted equality in green hold ?

for example if you take $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$

$D^2f = 2I_d \implies \| D^2f \|_{\infty} = 2$

but $\Delta f = 4 > \| D^2f \|_{\infty} $

so is $\| D^2f \|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})}$ something totally different from $ \| D^2f \|_{\infty}$ ?

Comment: He doesn't seem to be claiming that $\|D^2f\|\geq \|\Delta f\|$, but rather $C\|D^2f\|\geq \|\Delta f\|$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: @Bowditch yep, thanks for noting. I should've paid more attention.

Comment: In your example, according to the Evans notation, isn't $ \| D^2f \|_{\infty}=\sqrt{8}$?

Comment: @Pedro why would that be? the infinite norm of the identity is $1$ so it would be $2$ if you pull out the $2$ by the properties of the norm.

Comment: Appendix A says that $\|D^2 f\|_\infty=\||D^2 f|\|_\infty$, where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @Pedro I see, I haven't checked the Appendix at all but in that case, yes that would be $\sqrt{8}$, thanks for noting.